# Bootstrap grid system not applying

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I have a problem reoccurring in my project. I have a component `ProductCard` and I render in the `Home` component. So this is the ProductCard component

```
<div className={location.pathname === "/store" ? `gr-${grid}` : "col-3"}>
      {data &&
        data.length > 0 &&
        data.map((item, index) => (
          <Link
            key={index}
            to="/store/product-view/:id"
            className="product-card position-relative"
          >
            <div className="wishlist-icon position-absolute">
              <button
                className="border-0 bg-transparent"
                onClick={() =>
                  dispatch(
                    addWishlist({
                      token: user.refreshToken,
                      data: { item: item._id },
                    })
                  )
                }
              >
                <img src="/assets/images/wish.svg" alt="..." />
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="product-image">
              {item.images.slice(0, 2).map((image, index) => (
                <img
                  key={index}
                  className="img-fluid"
                  src={image.image}
                  alt="..."
                />
              ))}
            </div>
            <div className="product-details">
              <h6 className="brand">{item.brand.name}</h6>
              <h5 className="product-title">{item.title}</h5>
              <Rating style={{ maxWidth: 90 }} value={item.totalRatings} />
              <p
                className={`description ${grid === 12 ? "d-block" : "d-none"}`}
              >
                {item.category.description}
              </p>
              <p className="price">&#36;&nbsp;{item.price}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="action-bar position-absolute">
              <div className="d-flex flex-column gap-15">
                <button className="border-0 bg-transparent">
                  <img src="assets/images/view.svg" alt="..." />
                </button>
                <button className="border-0 bg-transparent">
                  <img src="assets/images/prodcompare.svg" alt="..." />
                </button>
                <button className="border-0 bg-transparent">
                  <img src="assets/images/add-cart.svg" alt="..." />
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        ))}
    </div>
```

And this is where I render it inside the main component

```
<Container classProp="featured-wrapper py-5 home-wrapper-2">
   <div className="row">
      <div className="col-12">
         <h4 className="section-heading">Featured Collection</h4>
      </div>
          <ProductCard data={featuredProducts} />
  </div>
</Container>
```

This is the Container component

```
const Container = (props) => {
  return (
    <section className={props.classProp}>
      <div className="container-xxl">{props.children}</div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

It appears in a column instead of using the grid system. Please how do I make the Home component display in a row.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean grid layout from Bootstrap doesn't work at all? It's hard to tell what you are trying to achieve without code snippet or at least screenshot.

I think you are missing `container` class for Container component - `<Container className="container ...">`

Comment: if you're using React why not also use React Bootstrap?

Comment: @Kary I have uploaded the image you needed. So you see instead of the cards showing in a row it displays in a column

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ No please, I used only bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the col-3 to be returned by the map function

```
<div className="row">
   {data &&
     data.length > 0 &&
       data.map((item, index) => (
         <div key={index} className= "col-3">
            <Link
              to="/store/product-view/:id"
              className="product-card position-relative"
            >
              ......
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for nested grid layout here. Take a look at this example:

```
<MainContainer className='container'>
  <div className='row'>
    <div className='col-12'>
      <Container className='container'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-12'>
            <h4 className="section-heading">Featured Collection</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          {products.map(product => <Product className='col-3'/>)}
        </div>
      </Container>
    <div/>
  </div>
</MainContainer>
```

Comment: I have tried using chatGPT for a solution and this is exactly what it proposed. What happens it nothing is displayed at all. I was hoping since col-3 has been defined in the ProductCard It should pick it up from there.. Other portions of my code suffer the same senario

Comment: Technically `col-3` should be picked up. In your example header with `col-12` takes all available columns, so rest of the content wraps. Certainly that's part of the problem. However, it's difficult to debug looking only at code blocks. Snippet would make it much easier.

Comment: The issue I believe is coming fro ProductCard since the SectionHeading is in its own div